# Изменение размера изображения в зависимости от размера QFrame

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, анимация, qt-designer

Как отобразить разный размер картинки? 
Вот когда меню выдвинуто, пусть отображается значок апекса, 
а когда задвинуто, пусть отображается такая же картинка, но в уменьшенном формате.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Apex.py**:

```
import sys    
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QIcon 
from PyQt5.uic import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.menuvisible = 0
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1209, 747)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(34, 31, 46);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 160, 161, 591))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.weapon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 100, 121, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    ;\n"
"    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);      \n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.weapon.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.weapon.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        self.spravka = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.spravka.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 540, 111, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.spravka.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.spravka.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.spravka.setFont(font)
        self.spravka.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    ;\n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"\n"
"    }\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.spravka.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.spravka.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.spravka.setObjectName("spravka")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, 540, 61, 41))
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Nikita_Pfeyfer4.png"))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-30, 100, 81, 41))
        self.label_9.setText("")
        self.label_9.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Nikita_Pfeyfer2.png"))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.menu.clicked.connect(self.showmenu) 
        self.menu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 51, 51))

        self.menu.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/menu/Изображения/back.png);\n"
"border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"")
        self.menu.setText("")
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1211, 21))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 90, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(253, 253, 253);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 130, 241, 2))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 180, 261, 161))
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 0, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(194, 194, 194);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 121, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 170, 256, 351))
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 720, 201, 20))
        self.frame_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_4)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, -2, 101, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 360, 261, 161))
        self.textBrowser_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(309, 391, 161, 2))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(331, 219, 121, 2))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(870, 170, 256, 351))
        self.textBrowser_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #6c6c00;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
        self.line_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(897, 200, 201, 2))
        self.line_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_4.setObjectName("line_4")
        self.frame_5 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -1, 161, 170))
        self.frame_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);")
        self.frame_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_5.setObjectName("frame_5")
        self.mainmenu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_5)
        self.mainmenu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 161, 161))
        self.mainmenu.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/Fone/Изображения/_Logotip_Proz3.png); \n"
"border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"")
        self.mainmenu.setText("")
        self.mainmenu.setObjectName("mainmenu")
        self.frame_2.raise_()
        self.frame.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.line.raise_()
        self.frame_3.raise_()
        self.textBrowser.raise_()
        self.frame_4.raise_()
        self.textBrowser_2.raise_()
        self.line_2.raise_()
        self.line_3.raise_()
        self.textBrowser_3.raise_()
        self.line_4.raise_()
        self.frame_5.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Weapons"))
        self.spravka.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reference"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Menu"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Версия"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1.0 BETA"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Эта программа предназначена для того, чтобы помочь новичкам или опытным игрокам более лучше освоить игру</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">_Apex Legends_</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Тут ты найдёшь подробное описание каждого оружия,</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; text-decoration: underline;\"> </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">обвеса и прочих вещей.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">С уважением, Разработчик </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Всё для вас!"))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">Информация</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Программа находится в разработке, поэтому, пока что присудствует не вся информация </span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">Кому принадлежит</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Все данные, изображения и прочее из программы, принадлежат компании</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\"> </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; color:#6f6f0a;\">Respawn Entertainment</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Никому более.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Их материал был повзаимствован для помощи игрокам.</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "справка"))

    def showmenu(self):
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame, b'size')
        self.anim.setDuration(250)
        if self.menuvisible==0:
            self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(50,751))
            self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(161, 751))
            self.menuvisible = 1
        else:
            self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(161,751))
            self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(50, 751))
            self.menuvisible = 0
            #self.anim.finished.connect(self.hidemenu)
        self.frame.show()
        self.anim.start()

import ApexFone
import menu

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я покажу вам возможное решение того, что вы хотите сделать.

Установите свои изображения и запустите мой пример.
Автоматический выполнится некоторые анимации.
Затем нажмите на кнопки в произвольном порядке.

Затем попробуйте изменять размеры окна.
Попробуйте также изменять размеры окна вашего приложения
и почувствуйте разницу.

Я вам уже писал, что без менеджеров компоновки вы далеко не уедите.
Чем быстрее вы освоите данную тему, тем лучше будет для вас.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ImageLabel(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene())
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff) 
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def setImage(self, filename):
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(filename))

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        item.setTransformationMode(QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        self.scene().addItem(item)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        r = self.scene().itemsBoundingRect()
        self.fitInView(r, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        super(ImageLabel, self).resizeEvent(event)
        

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(640, 480)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet(
            "#listWidget {background-color: #753422;}")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.listWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.image = ImageLabel()
        self.image.setObjectName("image")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.image)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(
            20, 40, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding
        )
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)        

        self.listWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        self.listWidget_2.setObjectName("listWidget_2")
        self.listWidget_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #D79771;")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget_2)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.listWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")        
        self.image_2 = ImageLabel()
        self.image_2.setObjectName("image_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.image_2)        
        
        self.listWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        self.listWidget_3.setObjectName("listWidget_3")
        self.listWidget_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: #B05B3B;")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget_3)
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.listWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")        
        self.image_3 = ImageLabel()
        self.image_3.setObjectName("image_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.image_3)
        
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Нажми меня"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "и меня нажми"))
        

class DemoImageLabel(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.image.setImage("boy.jpg")        # установите свое изображение !!!
        self.image.setMaximumHeight(200)
        self.image_2.setImage("lena.jpg")     # установите свое изображение !!!
        self.image_3.setImage("fg.png")       # установите свое изображение !!!
        
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.animate_listwidget2)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.animate_listwidget3)

        self.animation1 = self.build_animation(self.listWidget_2)
        self.animation2 = self.build_animation(self.listWidget_3)
        
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.animate_listwidget2)        
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.animate_listwidget3)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.animate_listwidget2)        
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(6000, self.animate_listwidget3)

    def build_animation(self, listwidget):
        animation = QPropertyAnimation(listwidget, b"maximumWidth")
        animation.setDuration(800)
        animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.Type.Linear)
        return animation

    def start_animation(self, animation):
        width = animation.targetObject().width()
        animation.stop()
        animation.setStartValue(width)
        animation.setEndValue(0 if width != 0 else 350)
        animation.start()

    def animate_listwidget2(self):
        self.start_animation(self.animation1)

    def animate_listwidget3(self):
        self.start_animation(self.animation2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DemoImageLabel()
    w.resize(800, 600)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я не вообще не могу понять, как сделать компоновку на моё приложение... Я что-то пытаюсь, пытаюсь, но либо что-то пропадает, либо что-то ещё. Не могли бы вы продемонстрировать это на моей программе. Какие куда лайауты ставить и куда спейсеры. Хотябы одно окно (Apex.py), я добавил в коде выше. Можно и формате ui, а дальше я буду разбираться

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер то есть мой ответ для вас даже не полезен? Если у вас есть проблемы с установкой менеджеров компоновки - создайте новый не большой пример, где вы пытаетесь это сделать и опубликуйте его. Также опишите что вы хотите сделать и прикрепите изображение, которое покажет чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: я сейчас задам новый вопрос

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер вы ничего не перепутали с принятием решения по ответам?

Comment: перепутал извините

Answer (score 2):

Создайте дополнительный ассет - картинка с необходимым вам размером, после чего, когда выполняется функция "сворачивания" меню, программно меняйте **background-image** через изменение **css-свойств** (stylesheet) объекта.

Например, так:

```
class MainWindow():
...

    def wrap_menu(self, *args):
    ...
    
    self.menuLogo.setStylesheet("background-image: url(small-logo.png);")
    ...
```